# How to disable inline preview in certain parts of document while editing?

Tags: auctex, preview

I'm using AUCTeX+emacs, and have inline preview enabled (although it could apply to other preview enabled editor like TeXstudio). My document has a TiKZ plot generated using `gnuplot`, and it has lots of items (drawn lines). When generating inline preview in AUCTeX, the computer had a big swap thrashing as soon as it comes to the part with the figure plot. I don't need preview for the plot, as it won't display correctly anyway as a dvi output. So I want to disable preview only for this part.

I confirmed that enclosing the figure with a `nopreview` environment will disable inline preview, but then it spouts out error when compiling normally.

**Question:** What is the right way to disable preview on parts of the document?

Comment: I don't know if I got your question right. But why not simply comment the parts you don't want out? With a `%` at the beginning of a code line.

Comment: @Lorzen That means I have to uncomment it everytime I need to compile.

Comment: AUCTeX's preview works by inserting generated images in place of the edited equation/figure. See this screenshot for example: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/img/preview-screenshot.png

Comment: Oh. I totally missed you are using emacs. Here could be a suitible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5612108

Comment: and this one http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CommentingCode